# Videos show nothing on Kodi 14.1

Tags: raspbian, kodi

I'm quite new to Linux so bear with me please. I have Kodi installed and tried to run the Youtube add-on. When I try to watch the video, I have the sound and it shows the picture of the Youtube channel, but there is no video to show. I only see many squares rotating.

I tried to find an answer to this question myself, but I couldn't find anything.
I also run the latest NOOBS on my rpi.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling Youtube addon.  Go to Video, addons, go to Youtube channel, right click, uninstall the Youtube channel.  Once you do that, try reinstalling it.  If that doesnt fix your issue, the Youtube package might be bad.  Hope that helps.